# Persistent indentation error on trinket.io and repl.it - cannot be removed

Tags: python, indentation

The following code (see full trinket below) is showing up an error on Line 22,suggesting it is an indentation error, but there is no indentation error.

Can anyone shed any light on this and how to fix the problem?

https://trinket.io/python/c4865547ad

This is the specific bit of code, cut and pasted below:

```
def register():
    print("register your details")
    print("first thing is- sign up and tell us a bit about yourself!")
  firstname=input("enter first name:")
  lastname=input("enter last name")
  username+firstname+lastname{[0]+"-member"
  print("your generated usernameis:",username)
```

I notice further that when I paste it in notepad or even above, the indentation is messed up. I correct this in another IDE or notepad and paste it back into trinket.io or repl.it and it still comes up with the indentation error.

What can be done?

Comment: At least in the code posted here, the indentation is very wrong. `firstname=` and the three lines under it need to be either at the same indent level as the `print`s, or the `def`.

Comment: please read what I've written. I've corrected that  - and you can try to do so in the trinket -and it keeps reverting back. Actually try doing it on the trinket and you'll see what I mean. The indentation error is persistent.

Comment: I'd just use a better editor. Online interpreter editors are often bad. If their editor is broken, there's little point in wasting time on it. Yes, when I paste the code elsewhere, it's messed up; despite what Trinket shows.